Include a YAML template that extends another
Back in the days I created a yaml template which encapsulates the deployment steps for one application. There are several pipelines which are extending from this template (passing the specific parameters to the template to deploy an specific app) working like a charm.
Now it is necessary to create a pipeline which deploys not one but n applications exactly in the same way, but my template only works for one. The obvious answer would be "take the deployment steps, put them in a different template, include the new template and call it n times". But I need to extend (my current template is the required template to access a protected resource).
So, Any suggestion to deal with this? My first thought is: Can I, in some way, include a template which extends from another?

What are the data types of the extends template parameters? steplist? joblist? stagelist?

Can I, in some way, include a template which extends from another? - I'm afraid not. According to the pipeline definition, a pipeline can only extend from one particular template.

Hi @RuiJarimba, currently, the template which I am extending from receives: AppName (the name of the App where to deploy), BuildPipeline (the name of the pipeline where the build artifacts are), previousJob (a job to execute before the deployment job)

Hi @RuiJarimba, The way I see it, if I Include a template which extends from another I am still extending only from one particular template

@Josto depends on what you mean by extend. What I was trying to say is that AFAIK you cannot use the extends keyword multiple times in your pipeline, directly or indirectly.

But of course you can use templates that reference sub-templates.

@RuiJarimba, I understand now: because I am including a yaml with an extend multiple times I am also including the "extend" keyword multiple times. Got it, Thank you.

Based on your description, you need to use required template feature in Azure DevOps. In this case, the extend template is required to be used in YAML sample.

it is necessary to create a pipeline which deploys not one but n applications exactly in the same way, but my template only works for on

If you need to add include template in the main yaml and use the extend template in the child yaml, this is not supported.
To meet your requirement, you can use the extend template in the main yaml and use include template in the child yaml template file.
Here is an example:
Main yaml:
parameters:
  - name: APPs
    type: object
    default: [1,2,3]
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

extends:
  
  template: test1.yml
  parameters:
    APPname: ${{ parameters.APPs }}

Child YAML template:
parameters:
  - name: APPname
    type: object

jobs: 
- ${{ each parameter in parameters.Appname }}:  
  - template: test.yml

Yaml template which encapsulates the deployment steps
jobs:
- job: 
  steps:
  - xxx

Result: You can input the names of the apps and the each expression will loop the value and run the templates.

Note: In this case, you need to change the required template to the child Yaml template.
Update:
Refer to the following sample to create object type parameters with three params:
Main yaml:
parameters:
  - name: APPs
    type: object
    default:
      - Appname: test
        Pipelinename: test
        JobName: test
      - Appname: test1
        PipelineName: test1
        JobName: test1
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
variables:
- group:  test
extends:
  
  template: test1.yml
  parameters:
    APPObject: ${{ parameters.APPs }}

Child YAML template:
parameters:
  - name: APPObject
    type: object

jobs: 
- ${{ each parameter in parameters.APPObject }}:  
  - template: test.yml
    parameters:
     appname: ${{ parameter.Appname }}
     PipelineName: ${{ parameter.Pipelinename }}
     JobName: ${{ parameter.JobName }}

Yaml template which encapsulates the deployment steps
parameters:
  - name: appname
    type: string
  - name: PipelineName
    type: string
  - name: JobName
    type: string
jobs:
- job: 
  steps:
  - script: echo "${{parameters.appname}}"


Hi @Kevin Lu-MSFT, If I am understanding well your proposal is to provide the list of the apps to deploy to the template which I have to extend from using an array. Is this correct? (I am not entirely sure which content corresponds to test1.yml and test.yml)

@Josto yes. You understanding is correct. We can use array parameters to loop the apps to run the template. And test1.yml is the child template yaml.  the test.yml is the yaml with deployment steps.

@Josto When we use parameters and each expression to loop the apps, you can directly control the apps value in main yaml. The agent jobs will be added based on the number of apps

Ok, your proposal is more or less my "plan B" to deal with this. The "problem" here is the fact that every app to deploy is not only the app name, but also the name of the pipeline with the artifacts and a previous job (total: 3 parameters). Do I need 3 arrays or can I model this with some kind of "complex" object with the three params?

@Josto Yes. We can  model this with some kind of "complex" object with the three params.  please wait a minute. I will share a sample with you.

@Josto Please check the update in the answer. It can model this with some kind of "complex" object with the three params.

Using parameters for this seems a bit weird, but reading this seems like the only option. Thank you
